Load jQuery in the head instead of the footer
I need to load jQuery in the header instead of the footer?
I tried adding header: true to global-styling in *.libraries.yml, but this had no effect.
global-styling:
  version: VERSION
  header: true
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery

Can I disable the core jQuery someplace, and add jQuery myself instead?

In the event this is an "XY problem", would you please add to this post the reason why this is needed?

You are fixing the wrong problem. Read about Drupal's JavaScript behaviors, so you don't have to load jQuery in the header.

You can implement hook_library_info_alter(), and override core/jquery as follows:
function HOOK_library_info_alter(&$libraries, $extension) {
  // Update imaginary library 'foo' to version 2.0.
  if ($extension === 'core' && isset($libraries['jquery'])) {
    $libraries['jquery']['header'] = TRUE;
  }
}

